# How can I make Ubuntu not go to sleep when I close my laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, sleep, login-screen

I use Ubuntu 10.10 on a laptop. I changed the "blank screen" settings at "System preferences -> Power management" and "Screensaver" and when I am logged in I can close the lid without going to sleep.

However, when I am at the login screen where I can choose a user, the behaviour is different. Ubuntu hibernates when I close the lid.

How can I change this so that only the screen blanks when I close the lid at the login screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go back to **Power Management** and click **Make Default**. The options will then be set for root (and default for all users), thus giving you the same behaviour when not logged in.

[image: Power Management]]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this from the command line, set `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.

Then do a `service systemd-logind restart`.